# AWS CloudFront: Content not immediately available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use CloudFront as the CDN in front of my S3.  I have a bucket for the media that users can upload, one type being an image and the other a video.  When the users upload an video, AWS's elastic transcoder transcodes the video into an HLS streaming playlist, an MP4, and a thumbnail.  My problem is that when I am uploading my media, it is immediately transcoded and placed in the bucket as it should, but my cloudfront url returns Access Denied.  I tried using a different cloudfront URL to the same path to test, and they never consistently worked.  Sometimes, one would have the content and the other wouldn't.  Also, changing to HTTP from HTTPS seems to work sometimes.  Is CloudFront supposed to not work immediately, and if not, what could be causing it?

Comment: Is your bucket in US-Standard, or a different region?

Comment: terpak, does the content eventually becomes available on the link where you have seen Access Denied? Anyway, answering your question - yes, content on CloudFront should be immediately accessible when corresponding file is uploaded to the origin (S3 in this case).

Comment: @AlexZakharenko you're right, in principle, but... S3 in US-Standard, unlike the other S3 regions, does not guarantee immediate read-after-write consistency on `PUT` operations of new objects.  It is possible that a new object in that S3 region will not always be immediately available for download within micro- or milliseconds after upload, as objects are in the other S3 regions.

Comment: The other question raised here is what OP means by the phrase "immediately transcoded."  Transcoding isn't quite immediate, even when it's fast.  There is necessarily some delay.

Comment: I have the same issue, S3 bucket in eu-west-1. Shortly after uploading to S3 an image can be accessible directly on S3 but not via Cloudfront for a few seconds. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment made an hour ago, I had the same issue for images uploaded to/hosted on AWS S3. Some images could not be accessed via Cloudfront for a few seconds after upload, but could be accessed/loaded directly on S3.

The eventual solution was to create a duplicate replacement Cloudfront distribution (with the same settings) to replace the existing one.